# How does PUBLIC external DTD files read? Where are these DTD Files located?

Tags: xml, hibernate, dtd

Hibernate config file has this DTD (document type Definition) specified.

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
```

What does this path present "`-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN`" . There has to be an actual DTD file which is being referred?

If not, `"hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd`' were this file is located or from were my code gets those files?

Answer (score 0):

It's called a Public Id. It's an identifier, not a location, so it's only useful if the parser has access to a catalog that lists known Public Id's and maps them to locations: typically you configure the parser with an `EntityResolver` or `XmlResolver` that accesses a catalog, for example using the resolver at https://github.com/xmlresolver/xmlresolver

But by default, the parser will use the System Id, that is, the URL http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd and will try to fetch the DTD from there, by making an HTTP request. If you do it very often then it's much better to redirect the request to a local copy.